# Get index of an element of an array in a loop

Tags: php

I would like to get the index of the current element of an array in a loop.
If I have this exemple :

```
<?php
  $array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
  foreach($array as $elem)
  {
    echo $elem;
  }
>
```

How could I get the index of elem in this loop (ex: 1 for 'b') ?
I tried current($array) but the return value stay at 0 in my loop but with print_r() I have this.

```
print_r($array);
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e )
```

Have you got any idea ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: `foreach($array as $idx => $elem)` then the index is in `$idx`

Comment: Please start taking a look around the excellent documentation. It will allow you to learn loads of useful things: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: With a new php version also: `print array_flip($array)['b'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want all keys in an array, you can use `array_keys()` function.

If you want to check a key does exist in your array or not, use `array_key_exists()` function like:
`array_key_exists ( $key , $array );`

or you simply want to access your keys, use `foreach()` like:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo 'Key = '.$key.' , Value = '.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo $key;                              //<- for testing

  if($value==mayval)echo "The key is $key";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach ($array as $k => $v)`

```
<?php
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
  echo $k . ' => ' . $v . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
0 => a
1 => b
2 => c
3 => d
4 => e
```

https://eval.in/772092